# How to connect delegate and data source?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tapku

I am trying to follow these instructions but now I am stuck.

**In your view controller:
Add an outlet for the TKCalendarMonthView.**

```
@interface YourViewController () <TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource, TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TKCalendarMonthView *calendarMonthView;
@end
```

**In -viewDidLoad, connect TKCalendarMonthView's delegate and data source. Note, you can also do this in the Storyboard if you first add the IBOutlet annotate to the delegate and dataSource properties in TKCalendarMonthView.h**

```
@implementation YourViewController
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
...
self.calendarMonthView.delegate = self;
self.calendarMonthView.dataSource = self;
```

I have this code in my project but overtime I run it I get this

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TapkuLibrary.h"
#import "TKCalendarMonthView.h"

@interface ViewController () <TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource, TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TKCalendarMonthView *calendarMonthView;

@end


@implementation ViewController Method 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.calendarMonthView.delegate = self;
self.calendarMonthView.dataSource = self;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

It successfully loads but then stops because of **calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate:'in protocol 'TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource' not implemented**

I guess my question is how do I connect TKCalendarMonthView delegate and data source in my viewDidLoad because thats what I didn't do in the instructions since I don't know how and I think that's what's causing this.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Check out the following: [Connect User Interfaces to Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/chapters/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW3) that will set you on the right track. I would also recommend checking out [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) for some basic storyboard tutorials

Comment: Command + Click on `TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource` and check out the `calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate` method in .h file. You need to implement this method in your class.

Comment: I Command + clicked on 'TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource' and it took me to the .h file and highlighted this '@protocol TKCalendarMonthViewDataSource <NSObject>' . How do I implement 'calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate' into the .h file? @WorldOfWarcraft

Comment: You can see the method within the protocol, and in your viewController, you need to implement this method, so copy this method to your viewController.m file and fill it.

Answer (score 1):

***READ IT AGAIN***, it says *not implemented*.

That means, you need to implement `calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate:` in your code...

Regarding delegate, you have already done by use of below statements in viewDidLoad.

```
self.calendarMonthView.delegate = self;
self.calendarMonthView.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method "calendarMonthView:marksFromDate:toDate" of DataSource protocol